# Updating an API using import/export tool in WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

API manager import/export tool is useful in a situation where the api is not available at all in the target environment. What is the best way to move the updates to an API from one environment to another, without incrementing the API version?

I can think of a way to remove the API in the target environment, and import the updated API zip file again. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue has been fixed in wso2am 2.1 version. Following is JIRA opened for exactly same scenario you have explained above. 
[APIMANAGER-4569](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4569)Support updating an API with API import tool

[WSO2-API-Manager-2-1-0 release note](http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/WSO2-API-Manager-2-1-0-Released-td146359.html) says so.[APIMANAGER-4569] - Support updating an API with API import tool

I have not try it myself, you may want to try new version. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this using the API manager 2.1.0, but the import throws the same exception : Error occurred while adding the API. A duplicate API already exists. From the documentation of API managetr 2.1.0, I noticed that the import-export tool is still the same ( api-import-export-2.0.0-v0.war). I could not find any other specific command (other than import)for updating the API

Comment: You are right, i try myself with new version and i got same error "A duplicate API already exists". I was trying to look in to code of import/export api (https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v2.1.0/modules/api-import-export) and see if i can find some kind of flag. no success yet, will update here if i get something.